# Rename sql-azure tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tagging

Proposing [sql-azure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-azure) be [renamed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197731/194636) to [azure-sql-database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database)

There are two quite separate relational database products from Microsoft:

1. [Azure SQL Database](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) (the target of this tag)
2. [SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server/)

Confusion may arise with the current tag because SQL Server can also be [hosted on an Azure Virtual Machine](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/sql-server/).

[sql-azure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-azure) should become [azure-sql-database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database) and used exclusively for `Azure SQL Database` questions.

Questions about SQL Server on an Azure Virtual Machine could be tagged [azure-vm](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure-vm) where the distinction is important, in addition to the usual [sql-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tags.

I have not created [azure-vm](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure-vm) yet, pending feedback on this proposal.

---

Examples of existing questions that might be tagged [azure-vm](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure-vm):

[Does installing SQL Server Database Engine and Reporting Services in Azure require two virtual machines?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34594/1192)
[SQL Server Transaction Logs in the Cloud](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/33175/1192)
[How to use Blob Storage as shared storage in a Windows Azure Failover Cluster?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/57124/1192)
[Sql Server 2012 Disk I/O Too high](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/76114/1192)
[SQL Server storage limits on Azure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/58297/1192)
[Replication with FileStream](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/62554/1192)
[Should I update to sql server 2008 sp2 before restoring the db's or do the update after?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34702/1192)
[Select values from 2 tables with same properties](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/53981/1192)
[How to get more information from dm_exec_query_stats](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/77882/1192)

Comment: I like it. Creating the azure-vm tag might be fruitless though, unless you know of some questions that already exist to apply it to?

Comment: Azure VM tag, don't see a point as it is just a Windows server just hosted on Microsoft's cloud. I don't think it would bring any addition to a question. Unless you create tags for Amazon's service as well.

Comment: @ShawnMelton You mean like [amazonrds](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazonrds) and [amazon-ec2](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2)?

Comment: Yes, wasn't aware those were even out there. Guess it would only be fair to have one for Microsoft as well. You are probably going to see Azure VM associated with SQL Server I expect.